# TFS in visual studio 2015 and git

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, tfs

I already used git before, quite a lot, as well as visual studio. Here I am under visual studio 2015 and I used TFS with team explorer for the very first time. Everything went fine.

Even if the project directory is really too big to be hosted by my git repo, as all my code is under my git repo, I "checkouted" a new TFS image inside my git repo and now I have the following problem : in team explorer, both "connexions" appear

- the TFS of type "srvtfs"
- my git repo of type "local git repository"

whereas before only one (the TFS) was appearing.

I would like not to see my git repo in team explorer anymore as I wasn't seeing it before, with the condition that my TFS image directory stays in the directory of my git repo. How could I do that ?

Comment: Can you share detailed steps and screenshots?

Answer (score -1):

To remove a Git team project in TFS from Team Explorer, click **Manage Connections**--**Connect to Team Project**, then select the TFS you are using, and uncheck the the team project. In this way, you won't see this team project in Team Explorer:

[image]

[image]

To remove git repo from **local git repository**, just right click the project and select **Remove**:

[image]

Comment: I am not sure you understood, I have a git local reposoitory `toto` that contains a sub-sub-...-sub-directory `subntoto` that is the directory of the local image of aTFS. I don't want to see in visual studio's "team explorer" the "ambiant" git project, just the TFS. Obviously here I can't remove the git project, as it would remove the TFS (as it contains it) - btw visual studio doesn't even allow me to remove it ;-) So that you're answer does not answer my question.